# Serial connection between arduino and pyserial slows down after reopening

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I need your help with an issue I stumbled upon, when using a serial connection between an arduino and pyserial:

When I am using the serial connection for the first time, it is significantly faster, than when i am using the serial connection again.

Here's a bare minimum example:

Arduino-code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduino ready"); // Print when Arduino ready
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
      Serial.read();
      Serial.println(' ');
  }
  delay(1); // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Python-code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('COM5',9600,timeout=1)
print(ser.readline()) # Wait until Arduino is ready

for i in range(1,10):
    tic = time.time() # Start timer

    ser.write(b' ')
    ser.readline()

    toc = time.time() # Log time
    print("Serial write / read took %7.4f ms" % ((toc-tic)*1000))

ser.close()
```

Running the python code for the first time:

```
b'Arduino ready\r\n'
Serial write / read took  5.9998 ms
Serial write / read took  6.0000 ms
Serial write / read took  7.0000 ms
Serial write / read took  5.9998 ms
Serial write / read took  6.0003 ms
Serial write / read took  5.9998 ms
Serial write / read took  6.0000 ms
Serial write / read took  7.0002 ms
Serial write / read took  5.9998 ms
```

Running the python code again:

```
b'Arduino ready\r\n'
Serial write / read took 27.9999 ms
Serial write / read took 29.0003 ms
Serial write / read took 27.9999 ms
Serial write / read took 28.0001 ms
Serial write / read took 27.9999 ms
Serial write / read took 29.0000 ms
Serial write / read took 27.9999 ms
Serial write / read took 28.0001 ms
Serial write / read took 27.9999 ms
```

Actions that recover the speed of the serial connection:

- Unplug / plug usb-cable between arduino and pc
- Reprogramm arduino

Resetting the arduino via reset button doesn't recover the serial connection.

Any ideas how to achive the connection speed of the first connection when reopening the connection?

I am using python 3.6 and pyserial 3.4.
Do you need any further information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem no longer occurs when I increase the serial baud rate from 9600 to 28800.

I also found out, that the problem only occurs with my Arudino Uno clone. The serial connection speed does not decrease at baud 9600 when I'm using the original Arudino Uno.